# Shouldn't お疲れ様でございます be お疲れ様でいらっしゃいます？

Tags: keigo

When addressing a superior, I've often heard people saying お疲れ様でございます, but でございます is a 謙譲語 form. Since they are talking about how hard their superior worked, shouldn't the phrase be transformed to 尊敬語, ie お疲れ様でいらっしゃいます.

Answer (score 4):

ございます is not a 謙譲語 by itself. It's just a 丁寧語, something more politer than です/ます. Sometimes (で)いらっしゃいます is better as a 尊敬語 word, but I have never heard お疲れ様でいらっしゃいます, presumably because お疲れ itself is not a human being. こちらは先生でいらっしゃいます is fine, but こちらは先生のお財布でいらっしゃいます sounds funny.

By the way, I feel お疲れ様でございます is already uncommon, and no one around me actually use it. But this should depend on where you work at.

Comment: Wait, ございます is the 謙譲語 version of ある right? 丁寧語 would be あります。For example, a customer asks ～ありますか and the clerk answers はい、ございます

Comment: @kandyman デジタル大辞泉 (goo辞書) and 明鏡 do not say it's a 謙譲語. As I said, it's another 丁寧語, a politer version of です/ます.

Comment: ok can you link me that explanation? id like to read it in more detail. thanks!

Comment: @kandyman https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/78364/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%94%E3%81%96%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99/

Comment: ある and いる are not the same as です, as you seem to be confusing them. です/だ/ございます are copulae, whereas ある/いる are regular verbs.

Comment: @Kurausukun である is a copula just like です and でございます are, e.g., "我輩は猫である".

Comment: @naruto That's true, but that's not the same as ある, and the first post seemed to imply they thought this.

Comment: ＠Kurausukun, ござる is not a copula. I'm not confusing いる・ある with です. The point I was making is that ござる is given as a 謙譲語 version of ある in many textbooks. Therefore である (copula) becomes でござる (copula). My question related to whether a 尊敬語 form should be used instead of a 謙譲語 form. It has nothing to do with いる・ある.

Comment: @kandyman I don't own any paper textbook, but online materials written in Japanese (including dictionaries, blog entries, chiebukuro questions) generally say ござる/ございます is NOT a 謙譲語 but a 丁寧語/尊敬語. It's perfectly fine to say 質問はございますか ("Do you have any questions?").

Comment: @naruto Ok that's reasonable. But I wonder if you could use it in the following (hypothetical) situation: You are an employee and you are asking the company president if he has water. Could you say 社長はお水がございますか。 Okay I know it's a silly scenario, but is the use ofござる possible in a situation where you are asking a superior if they have something.

Comment: @kandyman You should say 社長はお水をお持ちですか (社長は水がある doesn't make sense in the first place). You can say 社長は質問はございますか, 社長はご趣味はございますか, etc.